# After action completed uncheck previously checked check boxes

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

Jobs feature, messages tab within the inbox there is a checkbox indicator in each message.  At the top right there are two buttons one to **mark unread** and one to **mark read**.  After you check a few messages and perform an action, for example, **mark read** the completion of this action should uncheck the checkboxes that were previously selected.

Current situation, I check 3 messages, I mark them unread.  I would have thought after the system marks them unread that the three checkboxes get cleared...otherwise the end user has to go back and uncheck them if he / she wants to perform another operation.

[image]

Comment: We're following gmail's behavior there I think.

Comment: Okay I think that is odd behavior though, even for gmail.  You can place it as an answer and I'll accept it as to close this issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We're following gmail's behavior there.

Comment: BTW I did not downvote you!